# Why is setOnErrorListener is not being called?

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I have two different phones (Panasonic and Samsung) with the same version 4.4.2 but for the Panasonic phone everything works fine and setOnErrorListener is being called but does not happen in Samsung phone. Any idea what might be the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add code, screenshot, everything which might help us to find a problem

Comment: `mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() { 

@Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what,
                                               int extra) {
//showing my dialog here
}

}):`